# Get the list of all Google excel sheets associated with Google account

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a application where

- User Will authenticate with there Google account
- Then can see all the sheets list there
- They can select to edit or update there sheets or they can create a new sheet and input there data

How can i do this ?

I tried with google sheets api v4

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your app description exactly matches the functionality already provided by the [Sheets start page](https://sheets.google.com/). Use that instead of writing your own replica of the same.